# Python multiprocessing update size of iterable

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

i have the following:

from multiprocessing import Pool

```
def process_elements(index_of_data_inputs):
     <process>
     if <condition>:
          # i would like to change the size of data_inputs 


if __name__ == '__main__':
     pool = Pool()                         # Create a multiprocessing Pool
     pool.map(process_elements, range(0, len(data_inputs))  # process data_inputs iterable with pool
```

how i can change the size of data_inputs and so change the number of times process_elements 
is called?

the work behind that i would like to parallelize is:

```
i = 0
while i < len(elements):
    new_elems = process_some_elements(x,y)
    if len(new_elems) > 0:
        elements = elements + new_elems 
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider simple example of communication between processes with multiprocessing module in Python:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
import random


def process_elements(num, comq):
    val = random.random()
    if val > 0.5:
        comq.put(1)
    return num, int(1000 * val)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # initial data
    numbers = list(range(10))

    # data structure fot communication between multiple processes
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = m.Queue()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        # get answer for original data
        ans = pool.starmap(process_elements, [(num, q) for num in numbers])
        print(numbers)
        print(ans)

        # create additional data based on the answer for initial data
        new_numbers = numbers[-1:]
        try:
            while True:
                new_numbers.append(new_numbers[-1] + q.get_nowait())
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        # get answer for additional data
        new_ans = pool.starmap(process_elements, [(num, q) for num in new_numbers[1:]])
        print(new_numbers)
        print(new_ans)
```

Comment: please can you comment your solution ? i mean describe

Comment: i can not accept your solution because you process just 1 time more the data. But i don't know how many times process_elements would update me the number of elements check my update on the question

Comment: i don't know how many times i should run # get answer for additional data
        new_ans = pool.starmap(process_elements, [(num, q) for num in new_numbers[1:]])
        print(new_numbers)
        print(new_ans)

Comment: @T-student It is a very simple working example. It illustrates communication between processes with queues - pretty common task described in detail by numerous tutorials and guides - one google query away from you. `I don't know how many times...` - use while loop and check if queue `q` empty or not after every step of `ans` calculation.

Comment: the problem is exactly this, i don't want use a while i would like something to update the "for num in numbers" while it is using running "process_elements"